# Adding 駄 on the beginning of the word

Tags: words, kanji, prefixes

I've met a word 駄女 だおんな though not sure if wrote it well in kanji.
Can I use this 駄 with other words? For example, like 駄先輩 or 駄宏 (with the name of a man)? 
Are there words that suit this scheme most and those, that can not be used for any conditions? Could you please provide some examples?

Comment: Did you run into 駄女 in writing or in speech?

Comment: ＠snailboat in speech. So maybe mistaken with a kanji.

Comment: You sure it wasn't ダメ女?

Comment: @kuchitsu pretty sure, as ダメ is often used, so I probably wouldn't notice.

Answer (score 3):

Having lived in Japan all my life, I have never seen or heard the word 「駄女」, so I could at least assure you that it would ***not*** be a common word at all even if you have actually seen/heard it used.  (I highly doubt that you have encountered the word in **real life**.)

> Can I use this 駄 with other words? For example, like 駄先輩 or 駄宏 (with the name of a man)?

Again, never seen/heard 駄先輩 or "駄 + personal name" -- never.

「駄{だ}」 simply is not used as a prefix to random words.  It is basically  only used in a fixed group of words to mean ***"cheap", "low-value", "low-quality"***, etc.

Most common among those words would include:

駄菓子{だがし} (cheap confectionary)

駄賃{だちん} (small amount of money given to kids for running errands)  This word is becoming more uncommon by the decades.

駄じゃれ (boring pun)

駄馬{だば} (workhorse, horse of inferior breed)

Answer (score 2):

駄 in established words such as 駄馬, 駄文 and 駄菓子 clearly means "bad" or "cheap", but it's basically not a productive prefix, and you should not attach it to an arbitrary word. In particular, you can never attach it to a proper noun like 宏 (although something like ダメ宏 is occasionally heard).

That said, 駄 is occasionally used by native speakers as a slangy/nonstandard prefix; for example I have seen 駄ゲー ("trashy game") more than a few times. If you absolutely sure you heard だおんな, it should mean "bad woman", as you suspected. (Still, I feel there is a high chance you misheard something...) I won't be surprised if a native speaker used 駄先輩 in a blog article, but it should be fairly rare.